# Show that if $X$ is compact and $x$ is the only point of accumulation of the sequence ${x_n}$ then $x_n$ converges to $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

> Show that if $X$ is compact and $x$ is the only point of accumulation of the sequence $\{x_n\}$ then $x_n$ converges to $x$.

How could I prove it, I know that for the convergence to be fulfilled I have to prove it by the definition of convergence, but since I use the hypothesis of being the only limit point.

Pd: Disculpen la traducción, mi inglés no es muy fluido.

Comment: How are $X$, $x_n$, and $x$ related?

Comment: @user251257 I think it's safe to assume $x_n, x \in X$.  Fiona -- What definition of compact is available to you?

Comment: Is your space  a metric space?

Comment: There is a useful technical lemma that says that $x_n \to x$ **iff** for any subsequences of $x_n$ there is further subsequence that converges to $x$.

Comment: @user251257 X is a topological space, $x$ is a limit point, and it is also the point to which the sequence $x_n$ must converge.

Comment: @RobertShore no, it is a topological space

Comment: @user251257 yes, it is safe to assume that. The first definition we saw was the most basic, $ X $ is compact if each family of open $ A $ that covers $ X $ we can extract a finite subfamily that covers $ X $. In addition, we are following two books, topology-Munkres and topology- James Dugungji.

Comment: @copper.hat Is it applicable to a topological space?

Comment: @FionaEverdeen: Yes, and it is straightforward to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(x_n)$ does *not* converge to $x$, then there is some open set $O$ containing $x$, such that $X\setminus O$ is infinite, i.e. $M:=\{n: x_n \notin O\}$ is an infinite set. If $A:=\{x_n: n \in M\}$ is finite, then some $p \notin O$ occurs infinitely many times, and we have a new accumulation point of $(x_n)$, a contradiction. So $A$ is infinite and thus has an $\omega$-accumulation point in the compact subset $X\setminus O$ and again we have a new (not $x$) accumulation point of $(x_n)_n$. So we always get a contradiction and $x_n \to x$ after all.

Comment: His test is very interesting, but I cannot understand the construction of set $A$.

Comment: @FionaEverdeen $A$ is the set of sequence points that are not in $O$, see the definition. What’s not to understand?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Show that if $U$ is any open nbhd of $x$, there are only finitely many $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\notin U$. To do this, suppose that there are infinitely many $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\notin U$. There are two possibilities:

- There is some $y\in X\setminus U$ such that $\{n\in\Bbb N:x_n=y\}$ is infinite. Why is this impossible?
- $\{x_n:x_n\notin U\}$ is infinite. Then $\{x_n:x_n\notin U\}$ is an infinite closed set with no accumulation point (why?); is this possible in a compact space?

Comment: The first point why $ y $ would be another limit point other than $ x $ and that contradicts the fact of the uniqueness of the limit point. For the second point, there is what I'm thinking.

Comment: @FionaEverdeen: You’re right about the first point. For the second, it may help to notice that if that set has no accumulation point, then every $x_n$ in it has an open nbhd that contains no other point of the set.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but it didn't break any rules if I say that since we know that $X$ is compact and that implies that it is compact by limit point then $A = \{x_n: x_n \not\in U \}$ for being infinity has a limit point and we arrive at the same contradiction as in the first point. Also, now that I've analyzed it a lot, I can't understand why in the first point the set $ \{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n = y \}$ exists. I imagine it has to do with the set $ A $ in that case it is finite, but I have not managed to see it.

Comment: @FionaEverdeen: The reason for the first case is that in principle we could have $A$ finite and $\{n:x_n\in A\}$ infinite. That is, we have to worry about the difference between a limit (or cluster) point of a **sequence** and a limit point of a **set**; for instance, the sequence $\langle 0,1,0,1,0,1,\ldots\rangle$ has two cluster points, even though the set $\{0,1\}$ has no limit points. Here that can’t actually happen, because that, as you said, would mean that at least one of the points of $A$ was another limit point of the sequence, but we have to check that.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_n$ doesn't converge to $x$, then there's an open set $U$ such that $x \in U$ and infinitely many elements of $x_n$ fall outside of $U$.  But $X \setminus U$ is compact, so that means $\{ x_n \} \cap (X \setminus U)$ has an accumulation point as well ([If $E$ is an infinite subset of a compact set $K$, then $E$ has a limit point in $K$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449764/if-e-is-an-infinite-subset-of-a-compact-set-k-then-e-has-a-limit-point-in)), contradicting the hypothesis that $x$ was the only accumulation point.

Comment: Sorry. Why $X-U$ is compact?

Comment: Let $\{V_\alpha \}$ be any open cover of $X \setminus U$.  Then $U \cup \{ V_\alpha \}$ is an open cover of $X$, so it has to have a finite subcover.  Remove $U$ from that finite subcover of X and you have a finite subcover of $X \setminus U$.

Comment: Excellent, but I can't find or demonstrate why if $ X-U $ is compact then that intersection must have an accumulation point.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449764/if-e-is-an-infinite-subset-of-a-compact-set-k-then-e-has-a-limit-point-in